# Treat argument as string in Tcl 'expr' statement

Tags: if-statement, tcl, expr

I'm using the short syntax of 'if' statement like this:

```
proc WriteParameter {Parameter Value} {
    # Ugly option - WORKS
    if {$Parameter eq "Unique"} {
        set Register ControlStatus
        set Data ${Value}0
        set Mask EF
    } else {
        set Register $Parameter
        set Data $Value
        set Mask {}
    }

    # Elegant option - DOESN'T WORK
    set Register [expr {$Parameter eq "Unique" ? "ControlStatus" : $Parameter}]
    set Data [expr {$Parameter eq "Unique" ? ${Value}0 : $Value}]
    set Mask [expr {$Parameter eq "Unique" ? EF : {}}]

    puts $Register-$Data-$Mask
    return 0
}
set Value 4E20 ;# Merely hexadecimal number
set Parameter Regular
WriteParameter $Parameter $Value
```

The problem is that in the elegant option, since the 'expr' statement always treats its arguments as integers, 'Data' gets the value of 4e+20, which is merely the scientific notation of 'Value'.

However, I need 'Data' to be 'Value' (for example, to write to an external register).

Any ideas?

Comment: A hacky workaround would be to prepend an underscore (or other) character to the "4E20" and then remove it later.

Comment: Well, except that now, you are no longer using `expr` and the returned value is being correctly returned, right?

Comment: You're right.. I've used the ugly way. But I'm looking for the elegant solution (I've added to the original question)

Comment: @HardwareEng. But could you provide both: keep the current one, then put the implementation with `expr` that should be working just like the current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `expr` language is rather different to the rest of Tcl. You have to care much more about syntax there. Putting things in `"`double quotes`"` can help.

```
set Register [expr {$Parameter eq "Unique" ? "ControlStatus" : $Parameter}]
set Data [expr {$Parameter eq "Unique" ? "${Value}0" : $Value}]
set Mask [expr {$Parameter eq "Unique" ? "EF" : {}}]
```

However, you might instead be better using `if` as that doesn't try to convert the results of its arms to a number (using *approximately* the rules for C constants) unlike `expr`.

```
set Register [if {$Parameter eq "Unique"} {string cat ControlStatus} {string cat $Parameter}]
set Data [if {$Parameter eq "Unique"} {string cat $Value 0} {string cat $Value}]
set Mask [if {$Parameter eq "Unique"} {string cat EF}]
# We can omit the else clause; the default is an empty string anyway
```

This depends on `string cat`, which was introduced in Tcl 8.6.3 (well, 8.6.2 but that had some bugs in it's I/O subsystem that you *really* want to avoid). If you're using anything from 8.5 up to 8.6.1, use this instead:

```
set Register [if {$Parameter eq "Unique"} {return -level 0 ControlStatus} {return -level 0 $Parameter}]
set Data [if {$Parameter eq "Unique"} {return -level 0 ${Value}0} {return -level 0 $Value}]
set Mask [if {$Parameter eq "Unique"} {return -level 0 EF}]
```

Yes, `return -level 0` just gives the value as its result. “Obvious and discoverable”…

If you're on 8.4 or before still (Upgrade, man! You're out of security support!) then you need a little helper procedure:

```
proc value {value} {return $value}
```

```
set Register [if {$Parameter eq "Unique"} {value ControlStatus} {value $Parameter}]
set Data [if {$Parameter eq "Unique"} {value $Value 0} {value $Value}]
set Mask [if {$Parameter eq "Unique"} {value EF}]
```

The `value` procedure above will work with later versions of Tcl too, but it gives less efficient bytecode.

---

However, for all the above I'd actually do something different:

```
set Register $Parameter
set Data $Value
set Mask ""
if {$Parameter eq "Unique"} {
    set Register ControlStatus
    append Data 0
    set Mask EF
}
```

I might also use `scan` to parse the value and `format` to do the composing of the results back to hex (if necessary). Like that, it'd be much easier to think about the *value* and not just the *representation*.